# Using VBA to lock 2x secondary sheets, while allowing Primary sheet to extract information while protected

Tags: excel, vba, substring

I would like to use VBA to protect 2 secondary (Project)(Service) sheets using the same password,
but allowing the Primary (Comprehensive) sheet to extract information from those sheets while protected.

I am currently using the below to protect the workbook as I need it to auto protect when the workbook is closed.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

   Dim xSheet As Worksheet
   Dim xPsw As String
   xPsw = "####"
   For Each xSheet In Worksheets
   xSheet.Protect xPsw
   Next
   End Sub
```

[Secondary (Project)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSVbw.png)

and i am using this to extract the information from those sheets, (Project)(Service)

```
Sub copyFormat()

 
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Worksheets("Project").Range("D9:TJ28").Copy
        .Worksheets("Comprehensive").Range("D10:TJ29").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .Worksheets("Service").Range("D9:TJ28").Copy
        .Worksheets("Comprehensive").Range("D30:TJ49").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With
 
 With ThisWorkbook
        .Worksheets("Project").Range("A9:C28").Copy
        .Worksheets("Comprehensive").Range("A10:C29").PasteSpecial
        .Worksheets("Service").Range("A9:C28").Copy
        .Worksheets("Comprehensive").Range("A30:C49").PasteSpecial
    End With

End Sub
```

As i would like everyone to have access the Primary (Comprehensive) sheet, to hit the "update" button with the assigned macro to extract the most UpToDate information from the secondary sheets (project)(service) without having to unlock them.

[Primary (Comprehensive)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2N9I.png)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated thankyou

Please see above details my current document information

Comment: When do the data change on sheets Project and Service? Because only then Comprehensive-sheet needs to be updated ...

Comment: we have 2 teams working in the secondary sheets scheduling so they contain significant information, the extract just takes the cell colour and copies it to primary sheet for easy viewing to know what resources we have available

Comment: Use UserInterfaceOnly while protecting.
Than you still can work on the sheet by code but the user not.
But be aware, the UserInterfaceOnly is lost when workbook is closed.
But it its much better then removing and setting the pw for  every action, because this is very slow - thanks to MS since Excel2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the unprotect/protect to your macro:

```vb
Sub copyFormat()
Dim xPsw As String
   xPsw = "####"
 
    With ThisWorkbook

        .Worksheets("Comprehensive").Unprotect xPsw   '<---- add this line of code

        .Worksheets("Project").Range("D9:TJ28").Copy
        .Worksheets("Comprehensive").Range("D10:TJ29").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .Worksheets("Service").Range("D9:TJ28").Copy
        .Worksheets("Comprehensive").Range("D30:TJ49").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With
 
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Worksheets("Project").Range("A9:C28").Copy
        .Worksheets("Comprehensive").Range("A10:C29").PasteSpecial
        .Worksheets("Service").Range("A9:C28").Copy
        .Worksheets("Comprehensive").Range("A30:C49").PasteSpecial

        .Worksheets("Comprehensive").Protect xPsw   '<---- add this line of code


    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Elite, works a treat thankyou legend!!!